# Let $G$ act smoothly on $M$, $(g,m) \rightarrow t_g (m) $ from the left. Why is $t_g \simeq id $ if $G$ connected?

Tags: differential-topology, group-actions, global-analysis

Let $G$ act smoothly on $M$, $(g,m) \rightarrow t_g (m) $ from the left. Why is $t_g \simeq id $ if $G$ connected? I've seen this statement, but have no idea how to use connectedness here. Does anyone has hints?

Comment: Please repeat the question in the body of your post. For those of us who read MSE on mobile devices, the TeX codes in the title are not translated into mathematical notation, but those in the body are.

Comment: Also, by $t_g\cong id$, do you mean that $t_g$ is homotopic to the identity? The symbol for that is $\simeq$ (`\simeq`), not $\cong$.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, I meant that $t_g $ is homotopic to the identity, thanks for that correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G$ is connected implies it is connected by arcs, you have a path $c:[0,1]\rightarrow G$ such that $c(0)=e, c(1)=g$, you can define $H(t,x)=t_{c(t)}(x)$. $H(0,x)=t_{c(0)}x=x$ and $H(1,x)=t_{c(1)}x=t_g(x)$.

Comment: Why connectedness implies path connectedness here?

Comment: Because it is a manifold (I assume $G$ is a Lie group).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. Then, it is clear now.